# get Cross-Origin Request Blocked error in django for one special url

Tags: python, reactjs, django, cross-origin-read-blocking

i used django and reactJs for my web application.
all of urls are ok but just a url get Cross-origin blocked error.
this is my urls.py:

```
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.order_view,name="order"),
    path('create-ticket',views.create_ticket_view,name="create-ticket"),
    path('get-tickets-list/<int:id>',views.tickets_list_view,name='get-tickets-list'),

    path('change-state/order/<int:order_id>/state/<int:state_id>/',
        views.change_state_order_view,
        name='change-state'),

    path('create-common-answer/',views.create_common_answer_view,name='create-common-answer'),
    path('get-common-answer/',views.get_common_answer_view,name='get-common-answer'),
    path('get-states/',views.get_states_view,name='get-states'),
    ]
```

and all of these are ok except one and that is :

```
    path('change-state/order/<int:order_id>/state/<int:state_id>/',
        views.change_state_order_view,
        name='change-state'),
```

code view :

```
@api_view(['PUT','DELETE','OPTIONS'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated,IsAdminPerm])
def change_state_order_view(request,order_id,state_id):
    try:
        order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    except:
        return Response({'error':'404 Not found...!'},status=404)
    if request.method == "PUT":
        order.operator.add(request.user)
    elif request.method == "DELETE":
        order.operator.remove(request.user)
    order.state_ticket_id = state_id
    order.save()
    return Response({
        'message':'عملیات با موفقیت انجام شد.',
        'result' : {
            'order' : order.id,
            'user_email' : request.user.email,
            'name' : request.user.name,
            'method' : request.method
        }
        })
```

and my reactJs code :

```
        const instance = axios.delete('http://MY_DOMAIN/api/orders/change-state/order/6273/state/1',{
            headers: {'Authorization': 'token 079054fc245dc0894f896c31cd2ce2924e68cdb3'}
          });
        console.log(instance);
```

Comment: Are you sure your domain is set correctly in that call? Is your ReactJS application served from the same domain? Maybe you've added `www.` to this URL when being on a URL without `www.` or vice versa?

Comment: @GwynBleidD No. my django script is on my server and my react application is on localhost:3000